# Terminologies related to "compact?"

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactness

A set can be either open or closed, and there can either be a finite or infinite number of them.

A "compact" set is one where every open cover has finite subcover.

Is there such a thing as a set that is covered by an infinite cover of open subsets, and what would it be called?

How about a set where the open cover has a finite cover of closed subsets?

Comment: I don't think there are names for them, but you sure can build them. As to the last question: Consider the standard topology on the real numbers, every set of the form $[x]$ is closed, and there's an infinite union of closed subsets $\cup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$, that covers every subset of the reals.

Comment: A topological space is compact if every cover by open sets has a finite subcover. This is much different than having a finite cover. Every topological space has a finite cover by open and closed sets, namely the space itself.

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE: A "compact" set is one that is "covered" by a finite number of open subsets. END QUOTE  That is WRONG, and this particular error leads to other mistakes.  It's not merely a set with a finite open cover; it's a set for which EVERY open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: Additionally a set can also fail to be open or closed, or be both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something which you may be interested in:

**open (closed) cover:** A cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ is called an open cover (or a closed cover) if each member of $\mathcal U$ is open (closed) in $X$.

Note that closed cover is not often appeared in the general topology. We always consider open covers of $X$.

**Lindelof:** A regular space $X$ is a Linfdelof space if and only if every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover.

**countably compact:** A topological space $X$ is called countably compact pace if $X$ is a Hausdorff space and every countable open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for Lindelöf spaces.  In those, every open cover contains a *countable* subcover.

In $T_1$ spaces, if we try to apply the definition for "compact set" and replace "open" with "closed," we run into a problem, since singleton's are closed.  For any infinite set $X$,

$$\bigcup_{x \in X} \{ x \}$$

is a "closed cover" of $X$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: It seems that spaces where every closed cover has finite subcover are sometimes called [strongly S-closed spaces](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22closed+cover%22+%22finite+subcover%22+%22strongly+S-closed%22). Equivalent condition is that the space contains a finite dense subset (see Theorem 3.3 in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/S0161171296000427).) I have found out about this when I was researching for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740020/questions-related-to-intersections-of-open-sets-and-baire-spaces).