# Why do we define compactness via (finite) open covers, why not closed?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I fully understand the notion of compactness, but today I as wondering why we restrict the coverings to consist of open sets? I understand there is a separate compactness formulation for closed sets using the finite intersection property, but intuitively, why must the covers be open in the standard definition of compactness?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2154452/21820) and also [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/a/19156) for 'intuition' about open sets in topology.

Comment: Work backwards. Start with an 'intuitive' property of compactness. Reason that the open covering definition gives you this.

Comment: @Tyrone: I'm not sure that is easy. The easiest intuitive property of compactness comes from sequential compactness, which is not as general as the topological notion.

Comment: @user21820 The Heine-Borel Theorem is the most intuitive compactness theorem I can think of.

Comment: Consider for instance any topological in which the singletons are closed sets (for example any metric space). Then any set $A$ can be covered by the "closed covering" $\bigcup_{a\in A} \{a\}$ and thus only finite sets can have finite subcoverings.

Comment: @user21820: I’m not sure that sequential compactness is any more intuitive than limit point compactness, but I agree with your main point, and the history of the concept supports that point: it took quite a while for people to realize that open covers having finite subcovers was the ‘right’ definition of compactness.

Comment: @Tyrone: I don’t agree: the Heine-Borel theorem is too obviously dependent on a metric environment to be a reasonable candidate.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I realize I never asked myself this question: Does preservation under continuous functions imply the open cover definition in any reasonable sense? If it does, perhaps it can serve as some motivation. In particular, EVT is an instance of this phenomenon.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I would consider a metric environment the best place to get an intuitive feel for many topological properties. Hence the suggestion.

Comment: @user21820: Continuous functions preserve both countable compactness and sequential compactness (though not limit point compactness), so they can’t help too much.

Comment: @Tyrone: That’s a common notion, but I think it a mistaken one: metric spaces are far too nice to be a good place to develop one’s intuition for topological properties. I actually learned topology via a slightly modified Moore method, starting with the definition of a topological space and gradually adding properties that make spaces ‘nicer’, and I still prefer this approach. I recognize, however, that many students are uncomfortable with it and want something familiar as a touchstone. For that purpose I prefer linearly ordered spaces to metric spaces: some familiar examples are readily ...

Comment: ... available, but there is *much* less temptation to generalize from them to topological spaces in general than there is with metric spaces, because the fact that they are special is much more apparent.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you! I still suspect there might be some characterization of compactness in terms of continuous functions, but I don't have a concrete idea in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an observation which doesn't answer your whole question (since it doesn't explain why we *should* expect the open cover definition to be useful) but I think may help clarify the intuition: namely, that the "closed-compact" property is pretty trivial, at least on well-behaved spaces.

Specifically, **every** infinite space satisfying a certain mild property (namely, the [$T_1$ axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space)) is non-"closed-compact." This is easy to see: in a $T_1$ space $X$ every singleton is closed and so $\{\{x\}: x\in X\}$ forms a closed cover of $X$ which of course has no proper subcover, hence no finite subcover if $X$ is infinite. Finite spaces meanwhile are boring according to either notion, since all covers of any type (open, closed, or even arbitrary) are finite. So "closed-compactness" can only be interesting on infinite non-$T_1$ spaces. This rather limits the notion's applicability.

Comment: I'll just mention that some people use the term [strongly S-closed spaces](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22closed+cover%22+%22finite+subcover%22+%22strongly+S-closed%22) for the spaces where every closed cover has a finite subcover. I have mentioned this in my poste here: [Questions related to intersections of open sets and Baire spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/740020). (I have later posted that one on MO: [Intersections of open sets and $\alpha$-favorable spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/163875).)