# Why, in topology, is continuity defined with inverse images?

Tags: general-topology

In topology we defined a continuous map to be a map between 2 spaces $f: X \mapsto Y$ such that if $U\subset Y$ is open then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Why did we use the preimage; why not say 'a continuous map always maps open sets to open sets'?

Comment: Because then the definition would disagree with the one we use in real analysis; not all open maps are continuous there.

Comment: Do you want $f: \mathbb{R} \to \Bbb R : f(x)=x^2$ to be continuous? It sends the open set $(-1,1)$ to the non-open $[0,1)$ but it does obey the inverse image definition.

Comment: Constant functions will also usually be continuous but not open.

Comment: I think the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097385/why-dont-we-use-closed-covers-to-define-compactness-of-metric-space_) is relevant here.

Comment: "Why did we use the preimage, why not say ' a coninuous map always maps open sets to open sets'?"  Because they don't.  $f(x) = 2$ maps $(0,10)$ to $\{2\}$ and $f(x) = \sin x$ maps $(0, 10)$ to $[-1,1]$ neither of which are open.  More to the point an open set can only have open sets mapped to it.

Answer (score 6):

The statement "a coninuous map always maps open sets to open sets" is false. A counter example is $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ . Then the open set $(-1,1)$ is sent to the non-open set $[0,1)$.

Comment: For additional fun, the same map, but viewed as $\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ would be continuous in the proposed sense. (But that trick does not work for $x\mapsto x^3-x$.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So let's take $sin(x)$ that maps $(-10,10)$ to $[-1,1]$ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because with your definition we would have to agree that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ (constant function) is not continuous in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. We don't want that to happen.

Now, in metric spaces we can define continuity with $\epsilon-\delta$ like it is being done in analysis. But then there is a theorem that a function $f:(X,d_1)\to (Y,d_2)$ between metric spaces is continuous if and only if for each open set $U\subset Y$ the set $f^{-1}(U)\subset X$ is open. You can take it as a good exercise to prove this theorem. And this is the motivation for the definition of continuity in topological spaces which are not necessary metric spaces. With this definition we get a generalization.